# Assign values to variables

Tags: bash, random, mac-address

openSuSE 13.2

I'm trying to assign a random value to `rand` and the MAC Address of the interface to `mac`

I've tried the following, but they didn't seem to work.

```
rand=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 6 | head -n 1)

eth=$(<ifconfig eth0 | awk '/HWaddr/ {print $5}')
```

`rand` should be 6 digit string containing a mix of letters and numbers.

Any ideas how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Start by removing the `<`

Comment: So whats the deal with the random value, why are you passing to tr and fold?

Comment: @123 I'm trying to return a 6 digit string containing a mix of letters and numbers.

Comment: @Tom Might be useful to add that to the question.

Comment: Also how do they not work?

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks removing the `<` has sorted `eth`  I think rand had a typo in it as it now appears to be returning correctly.

Comment: Sorry the rand value doesn't work. Running the command at the command line takes an age to return.  Any way to get this working ?

Comment: OK sorted it by using `openssl rand -base64 6`  that returns a random string I can use.

Answer (score 0):

A nicer way to get a random string might be something like:

```
rand=$(head -c 32 /dev/urandom | base64 | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c 6)
```

Where we first grab 32 bytes of randomness, feed that first to `base64` and then `tr` to get more legible characters and remove all but wanted chars and lastly grabbing just the first 6 bytes with `head`.
(Without the `base64` in the middle, some strings might not contain 6 characters).

This is far from optimal solution but should produce 6 alphanumeric characters with high certainty.

For reading the mac-address, you should probably use something like:

```
# bash process substitution reads the redirected output to a variable
eth=$(</sys/class/net/eth0/address)
```

As `ifconfig` is meant more for manual use and parsing the output is horror.